# How do I display mysql data in row span using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

How do I display mysql data in row span using Codeigniter ? I tried more times but could not ! I can display all data from MySql database but when I tried to do display data in row span then I failed !

Here is the screenshot. You will be clear what I have need :

http://prntscr.com/42t7ul

Please help me !

Thanks

Comment: Please share you corresponding code..

Comment: It looks like you want to do something like `rowspan`. If you are building your table rows while returning your db rows and don't know your `rowspan`, so you can use something like `$currDate = ''; yourWhileLoop($row = ....) { if($row['date'] != $currDate) { echo $row['date']; $currDate = $row['date']; } ... rest of your loop }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using views in Codeigniter, then you can use it this way:

```
foreach ($array_data as $date => $recs)
{
    $one_recs_cnt = count($recs);
    echo "<tr><td rowspan=" . $one_recs_cnt . ">" . $sno++ . "</td><td rowspan=" . $one_recs_cnt . ">" . $date . "</td>";
    foreach ($recs as $key => $data)
    {
        echo "<td>" . $data['category'] . "</td><td>" . $data['description'] . "</td><td>" . $data['author'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

And if your array values look like this:

```
Array ( [15-07-2014] => 
    Array (
            [0] => 
                Array ( [category] => Default1 [description] => xy [author] => A1 )
            [1] => 
                Array ( [category] => Default1 [description] => yz [author] => A2 )
            [2] => 
                Array ( [category] => Default1 [description] => xz [author] => A3 )
                )
            )
    )
```